# How to fix NumberFormatException when using gson.fromJson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have an arraylist saved in shared preferences, of custom objects (Book) and now that I've updated the app (added a new property called Progress, which is an int), it seems that gson is trying to put one of the longs into this int variable.

This only happens to select users, who download the app through the store and I haven't been able to reproduce it. I posted something similar but without enough information here yesterday and realised I posted too early.

Note: at myrr.auto1.myreadingrecord1.sharedFunctions.loadArrayList(sharedFunctions.java:40) is the 
    bookList = gson.fromJson(json, type); 
line

```
static ArrayList<Book> loadArrayList(Context context) {
    ArrayList<Book> bookList;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = mPrefs.getString("finishedBooks", "");
    if (json.isEmpty()) {
        bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Book>>() {
        }.getType();
        bookList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
    return bookList;
}


Fatal Exception: com.google.a.r: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 1538513480946 at line 1 column 1891 path $[0].i
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:227)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:217)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
   at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:888)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:853)
   at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)
   at myrr.auto1.myreadingrecord1.sharedFunctions.loadArrayList(sharedFunctions.java:40)
```

This is how the json string looks like, in old versions:

```
{"author":"Kerry Cohen Hoffmann",
"categories":"Juvenile Fiction",
"description":"Feeling neglected by her divorced parents and distant         older sister, fourteen-year-old Jessica discovers how easily she is able to         attract the attention of men and boys, without realizing the risks of her     behavior.",
"endTime":1546742469961,
"imageURL":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id\u003d7wLjQH5_HjEC\u0026printsec\u003dfrontcover\u0026img\u003d1\u0026zoom\u003d5\u0026edge\u003dcurl\u0026source\u003dgbs_api",
"language":"en",
"moreInfoLink":"http://books.google.com/books?id\u003d7wLjQH5_HjEC\u0026dq\u003deasy\u0026hl\u003d\u0026as_pt\u003dBOOKS\u0026source\u003dgbs_api",
"pages":"176",
"startTime":1546553627662,
"title":"Easy"}
```

And this is the Book class properties, the setters and getters are pretty normal so i didnt include them.

```
public class Book implements Serializable{
private String author;
private String title;
private String pages;
private String imageURL;
private String description;
private String categories;
private String moreInfoLink;
private String language;
private int progress = 0;
private long startTime = 0L;
private long endTime = 0L;

public Book (String author, String title, String pages, String description, String imageURL, String categories, String moreInfoLink, String language) {
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.description = description;
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
    this.categories = categories;
    this.moreInfoLink = moreInfoLink;
    this.language = language;
}
```

So for some, select users the fromJson tries to put the starttime or endtime value into the new progress property. How can I prevent this?

It should just create a new ArrayList of Book but it actually just crashes.

ADDING:

```
public void setEndTime(long endTime) {
    this.endTime = endTime;
}

public void setStartTime(long startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;}

theCRBook.setStartTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: You code works fine for me. Only edit I had to make was adding the square brackets since you are parsing this json into a list

Comment: Yeah, it works for me too, but some users crash and the only way is to completely remove application data (so shared preferences are deleted). I've even tried adding books on older branches and updating to the new one and it works for me.

Comment: @lasagnakid77 See my updated answer, I think it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038589/1475574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error shows, you enabled the `minifyEnabled` in the `build.gradle` in order to obfuscate the code. In this case you need to do the `@SerializedName("endTime")`, `@SerializedName("startTime")` ... etc. for every variable you have in the model because the name of that variable will be changed on release versions.

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("author")
    private String author;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("pages")
    private String pages;

    @SerializedName("imageURL")
    private String imageURL;

    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("categories")
    private String categories;

    @SerializedName("moreInfoLink")
    private String moreInfoLink;

    @SerializedName("language")
    private String language;

    @SerializedName("progress")
    private int progress = 0;

    @SerializedName("startTime")
    private long startTime = 0L;

    @SerializedName("endTime")
    private long endTime = 0L;

    public Book (String author, String title, String pages, String description, String imageURL, String categories, String moreInfoLink, String language) {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
        this.categories = categories;
        this.moreInfoLink = moreInfoLink;
        this.language = language;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've actually always had that enabled, just recently I changed the proguard settings to show line numbers. Where would I add this? In the book class where I got the strings/longs?

Comment: @lasagnakid77 I updated my answer and added the class and how it should be.

Comment: @lasagnakid77 Because Strings will not be changed after you enable minifying, the `@SerializedName("")`  will match the name of the shared preferences with the java variable

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have no way of testing if it fixes it but if theres no crashes in a day or so I'll accept the answer. Any idea why this only happens to some people? Do different phones minify differently or something?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have idea for that.

Answer (score 1):

The exception states `1538513480946` is too large to fit into `int`, which is correct. It's a timestamp for 10/02/2018 @ 8:51pm (UTC) and should be stored as `long`.

Perhaps you have an older version of `Book` class where `startTime` or `endTime` are declared as `int` and not `long` (or maybe just the setter parameter is `int`).

Comment: I've checked and both startTime and endTime have been longs from the start. I'm adding some more code related to those two fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this class for your book class:

```
public class Book {
    @SerializedName("author")
    @Expose
    private String author;
    @SerializedName("categories")
    @Expose
    private String categories;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("endTime")
    @Expose
    private long endTime;
    @SerializedName("imageURL")
    @Expose
    private String imageURL;
    @SerializedName("language")
    @Expose
    private String language;
    @SerializedName("moreInfoLink")
    @Expose
    private String moreInfoLink;
    @SerializedName("pages")
    @Expose
    private String pages;
    @SerializedName("startTime")
    @Expose
    private long startTime;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(String categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public long getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(long endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getMoreInfoLink() {
        return moreInfoLink;
    }

    public void setMoreInfoLink(String moreInfoLink) {
        this.moreInfoLink = moreInfoLink;
    }

    public String getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(String pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public long getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(long startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Just import gson in your book class:
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

After that, you can easily get some start/end time from your book array and convert it to date like this:

```
ArrayList<Book> books = loadArrayList(this);
Date date = new Date(books.get(0).getStartTime());
Log.i(TAG, "Date: " + date.toString());
```

You will get date from your json string:
Date: Thu Jan 03 17:13:47 EST 2019

Hope this can help you :)